# Can I close SSMS but leave a stored procedure running?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to shut down ms sql server management studio while a stored procedure is running, without stopping the stored procedure?

Comment: No. Why would you want to?

Comment: If you want to run your SP outside of SSMS, schedule it under SQL Agent.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean an SP you are running within SSMS then no. Obviously closing your own SSMS won't affect SP's that are running from other users on the server.

Answer (score 4):

You really can't,  however you can create a SQL Agent job which will execute the stored proc do you need a result set returned to you or are you updating data?

If its an update I think you're fine just running it from the agent, if not, your next simplest way to return a long running stored proc's result set would to be create an SSIS package which outputs that result set to a csv, excel doc what ever is appropriate.  This package can then also be executed by the SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you will not be able to see the result of the SP if something is returned. Once the execution is given to server the server will execute the SP not the SSMS.

Comment: Not true. If you shut down SSMS whilst the query is running it will ask if you want to cancel execution of the query. You can try `CREATE PROC Foo AS WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00' EXEC ('CREATE TABLE FooBar (X INT)')` then `EXEC Foo` then close down SSMS. Click "Yes" on the cancel dialogue and then reopen SSMS after a minute. No table called FooBar will exist.